# Accessing Django Foreign Key Object Values through Django Shell

Tags: python, django

How do I correctly access Foreign Key Values through the Django Shell?

I am trying to access the Foreign Key Values of the Placement Field (an integer from 1 to 8) through the Django Shell. When I query I receive values greater than 8 (the max of data currently entered), which is unexpected.

Django Admin Screenshots:

[Champion_Placement Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Syl.png) , [Match_Placement Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY2zr.png)

Query:

```
manage.py shell
from stats.models import *
Champion_Placement.objects.all('placement').values()

<QuerySet [{'placement': 10}, {'placement': 10}, {'placement': 10}, {'placement': 10}, {'placement': 10}, {'placement': 10}, {'placement': 10}, {'placement': 10}, {'placement': 10}, {'placement': 11}, {'placement': 11}, {'placement': 11}, {'placement': 11}, {'placement': 11}, {'placement': 11}, {'placement': 11}, {'placement': 11}, {'placement': 12}, {'placement': 12}, {'placement': 12}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models

class Summoner(models.Model):
    puuid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.puuid}'
    
class Match_Placement(models.Model):
    match_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    placement = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    puuid = models.ForeignKey(Summoner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.match_id} - {self.placement}'

class Champion(models.Model):
    champion_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cost = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Item(models.Model):
    item_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Champion_Placement(models.Model):
    match_id = models.ForeignKey(Match_Placement,  related_name='%(class)s_match_id',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    placement = models.ForeignKey(Match_Placement, related_name='%(class)s_placement', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    champion_id = models.ForeignKey(Champion, related_name='%(class)s_champion_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    champion_level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    item_1 = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='item_1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_2 = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='item_2',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_3 = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='item_3',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.match_id} - {self.champion_id}'
```

Comment: Your query, albeit wrong, will return the id(pk) of the relevant `Champion` model, which isn't always the number of existing instances+1 because of how model sequences work. To span relationships check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe to filter records by a Foreign Key Field Value (Placement in this case) you have to access it through the Match_Placement object, like so:

```
#get the placement_id of the placement
first_placement_id = Match_Placement.objects.get(placement=1).id
#filter using placement_id
Champion_Placement.objects.filter(placement_id=first_placement_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't khnow if this can help

```
e = Champion_Placement.objects.all()
e.placement
```

for more information

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects